# the map in label2rgb function

Tags: image, matlab, toolbox

I want to use the `label2rgb` function to construct a color image with a labeled image issued from a segmentation process.

So I compute a color map `n`-by-3 which contain the meanvalue of each region detected in the segmentation. and I make this:

```
Lrgb = label2rgb(L, coul);
```

where `L` is tha labeled image, but I got this error:

> ??? Error using ==> label2rgb>parse_inputs at 147
>   Invalid entry for MAP.
>
> Error in ==> label2rgb at 50 [label,map,zerocolor,order,fcnflag] =
>   parse_inputs(varargin{:});
>
> Error in ==> test at 241 Lrgb = label2rgb(L, coul);

Thank you,

Comment: try `ind2rgb` instead

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `max(L(:)) <= n` and that `min(L(:)) >= 0`, otherwise you'll get into trouble.

Comment: @mariem - what do YOU mean by `n`: "I compute a color map n*3". This `n` should be the number of labels in `L`.

Comment: I find the problem, in fact, it seems that the map matrix must have element value between 0 and 1

Comment: @mariem it should be a colormap - `n`-by-3 in range [0..1] of type `double`.